# How do I set up Box event notifications (webhooks) at the org level?

Tags: box-api

The documentation (http://developers.box.com/webhooks/) talks about webhooks in the context of "user's account".  I read that as getting notifications only about the objects to which I have access.

Let's say I want to be notified every time there is a new upload anywhere across my organization.  Do I need to be an admin to accomplish this, or is the webhooks scope not subject to my user permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we're continuing to enhance webhooks, there is some administrative functionality built-in.  For instance, if you can get your webhooks installed for all your users, and have the webhook point to one endpoint, that can track all activity in your account.

There is a way to force webhooks on all users in your domain as an administrator.  However, this feature hasn't been optimized for companies that use webhooks for internal use.  That's still in progress.

If you'd like to be kept in the loop, or try some workarounds with what we have, feel free to contact us at api [at] box [dot] com.  With more information, we may find something that works today, based on your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, the webhooks are only provided at the user level.  If you log on as an admin and setup an application that gets webhooks, you will only get the same set of notifications as you see in the "Updates" tab in the Web UI.

We are looking to expand the webhooks capabilities, and this is one area that we may explore.  However, it is not currently scheduled, so I can't provide any idea of even rough dates.